# TWebBrowser vs. TAutoIntfObject (DelphiDabbler)

Tags: c++builder

http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=1

I am trying to port Article-22 to C++

This line

```
TMyClass = class(TAutoIntfObject, IMyIntf, IDispatch)
```

"translates" imho to:

```
class TMyClass : public TAutoIntfObject, IMyIntf, IDispatch
```

But it cannot be compiled, since 
  a) IDispatch is already part of IMyIntf
and 
  b) some virtual functions will then be missing

Does anyone have an idea?